# 'Cloning' Ubuntu to my other PC?

Tags: backup, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.04, clonezilla, remastersys

I searched for available options and see mention of Clonezilla and Remastersys - but nothing I found answered my question completely...

My home PC is just a generic one, and now that I changed it to Ubuntu I really love how it's come out and how it runs better !
My office PC is a different generic set of hardware, and I'd like to 'clone' the exact same setup to it but not have to repeat all the tweaking and such that I did already.

(Home PC=>Asus MB/AMD CPU/Nvidia display card; Office PC MSI MB/AMD CPU/Nvidia display card. My query is because I wanted to be sure that since they have different chipsets that the restored configuration will be able to adjust if it must and boot up properly.)

The important questions for me:
1)Is there a program that will allow me to replicate/install my already customized setup from one to the other, easily ? 
2)Are there certain steps I must make before doing something like that so it'll be compatible with different hardware ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried CloneZilla and it failed to complete; searching for the error it threw proved to be a waste of my time...

Moved on to Remastersys and found that it is so primitive and lacking in options as to be useless; meaning that it cannot be told WHAT & WHERE to back up... a severe disappointment.
(I have a spare partition with lots of stuff stored in it - and there's no way to tell it NOT to back that up - which was further complicated by it telling me my data was too big for a CD...WHAT ?? A CD ??? I had a writable DVD in the burner and I guess it doesn't 'speak' DVD sometimes, so I just gave up on it.)

The best solution I've found:

Redo Backup [(here)](http://redobackup.org/)- holy cow is this great !!!

I was able to make my backup to my USB stick in an amazingly short period of time, and restored it quickly as well - and it booted right up with ZERO problems.

If there's anything else equal or better than Redo Backup I'd love to hear of it, but for now I am very, very satisfied.